# Namespace error with spring data neo4j

Tags: eclipse, spring, gwt, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

i´m currently trying to set up a test project with GWT, Maven, Neo4j and Spring Data.
I ran into a problem when I try to start the project in development mode in eclipse

I alway get the error

org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j]

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j-2.0.xsd">
```

This is the part of the application-context.xml which gives the error.

In pom.xml I use

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

But I also had the problem with the 2.0.0.Release version.

I found the same error here http://neo4j.org/nabble/#nabble-td3428668
but no answer is provided or if there is a fix.

Does someone have an idea where the problem is?

Comment: The namespace lookup files are in the jars in META-INF/spring.handlers . It might be that eclipse has some issues pulling them in? Perhaps also an m2e issue?

Comment: I tried to debug the namespacehandler loading. The only spring handlers which are loaded were the ones directly in the spring-core etc. but not the spring data spring.handlers. But now I changed so much to get the mvn gwt:run to work and the error doesnt appear anymore even when I start it in eclipse directly. But I cant see which change lead to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

What is your setup? I guess there is a classloader problem in that the neo4j namespace XML is sitting in another bundle and not accessible to the requesting bundles classloader. Could you put all the SDN jars into one big superbundle to get around this_